# Android AlphaAnimation that only fades out?

Tags: android, animation

Right now I have an AlphaAnimation that fades out, the problem is that my fade out animation run on something already faded out, causes it to appear and fade out, when I'd rather it simply stay faded out. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, check whether it's faded out and don't apply the animation then. :) Or initialise the starting value of the animation with the current property value of the object.